# Mysql error 1049 when importing db «ERROR 1049 (42000) base ‘undefined’ unknown »

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-code, wamp, mysqlimport

So basically when I try to import my database or any database even some that my teacher gave me. It does not work. And it says that «ERROR 1049 (42000) : Base ‘undefined’ unknown ». It does this at school and at home since Thursday before I never had this type of issue and I can’t ask a teacher they are in holiday and the thing is that when I logged in an other PC at school it worked but I can’t do it at home neither I can go to school because it’s close due to the summer vacation. I try import my database on visual studio code. I know that my database works because before Thursday I never had any problems and it still work on phpmyadmin. I only have the problem with visual studio code. By the way I use wampserver to serve my website. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewrite the question.